# Sensors for bicycle races

Tags: sensor, detector

First of all, i just completed my first year on Eletronic Engineering, so be soft.
So i'm thinking on creating a system wish can track the participants on a bycicle race.
Basically i need a couple of receivers(the less, the better) at the winning post, that receive the ID of a specific player who has the emitter on their bycicle or body. It is important that each emitter has an specific ID so i can know when each racer completed one lap.
What is the best technology for this purpose?I'm thinking on RFID, but i'm not sure..
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any reason a standard video camera at the finish line won't do?

Comment: Is it fairly likely two (or more) bikes could arrive at the finish line simultaneously (separated by only a couple of inches)?   Say 1st place on the right, 3rd place in the middle, 6 inches behind 1st place, and 2nd place on the left, 4 inches behind 1st place.  Contrived, but possible?

Comment: I've used an RFID device in a 10k run (foot race). [Here](http://www.rfidtiming.com/newsletters/newsletter-06-230311.html) is one supplier.

Answer (score 1):

RFID is an interesting choice. Its basically a data holder. You can enter the contestants details, dimension of the bike in the card. So now if you place this rfid under the seat you know the position of the bike tip.

Rfid reader units can be placed about 1,  0.5, meter before the finish line.

These units will relay the data to a database on a computer with time and rider details etc.

Its exactly what you want.

Comment: Have a look at these devices, they have been used in race cars and lots of other interesting applications.  http://www.rfid-radar.com/